# dropdownlist selection returning null @ mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to insert to database from view page which has dropdownlist , textbox's .. when i enter something and click on save means i am getting nothing from dropdown selection which is binded .

```
My code :

@model    IEnumerable<iWiseapp.Models.LObmodel>

@using (@Html.BeginForm("stop", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{


     @Html.DropDownList("Data",ViewBag.Data as SelectList,"select a sdsd",new {id="LOB_ID"})

                @Html.DropDownListFor("sss",new SelectList(Model,"lob_id","lob_name"))
                ,
                @Html.DropDownList("LObmodel", new SelectList(ViewBag.data ,"Value","Text"))

               @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.lob_name, new SelectList(ViewBag.Titles,"Value","Text"))
```

I tried above all possibilities but nah i am confused nothing working out

ADDED MY CONTROLER CODE

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult stop()
        {
            ServiceReference1.Service1Client ser_obj = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

            IEnumerable<LobList> obj = ser_obj.GetData(); //i am Getting list of data through WCF from BUSINESS LAYER WHERE i created entities via EF

        List<SelectListItem> ls = new List<SelectListItem>();

           foreach (var temp in obj)
        {  

            ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = temp.LOB_NAME, Value = temp.LOB_ID.ToString()           });
        }
        //then create a view model on your controller and pass this value to it
        ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
        vm.DropDown = ls;  // where vm.DropDown = List<SelectListItem>();


  THE COMMENTED CODE BELOW IS WHAT I AM DOING      


            //var mode_obj = new List<LObmodel>(); 
 //Created LOBmodel class in model which is excat same of entities in Business class 

            //var jobList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            //foreach (var job in obj)
            //{
            //    var item = new SelectListItem();
            //    item.Value = job.LOB_ID.ToString(); //the property you want to display i.e. Title
            //    item.Text = job.LOB_NAME;
            //    jobList.Add(item);
            //}
            //ViewBag.Data = jobList;
           return View(jobList);  or return view (obj)
        }
```

Any expert advice is appreciated

MY FIELDS , IS THESE PERFECT

```
public class template
    {
        public List<LobList> LOBs { get; set; } //LOBLIST FROM Entities in business layer

        public int selectedLobId { get; set; }

        public LobList SelectedLob
        {
            get { return LOBs.Single(u=>u.LOB_ID == selectedLobId) ;}
        }
    }

AND 

public class LObmodel
    {
        public int LOB_ID { get; set; }
        public string LOB_NAME { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend putting the selectlist into your model instead of passing it through the view bag.  The option you want is

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.lob_name, new SelectList(ViewBag.Titles,"Value","Text"))
```

you can set the selected item by setting model.lob_name on the controller and on post back that value will be set to the selected value of the dropdown

on your controller you can build the list like this

```
List<SelectListItem> ls = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach(var temp in model){  //where model is your database
    ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = temp.Text, Value = temp.Value });
}
//then create a view model on your controller and pass this value to it
LObmodel vm = new LObmodel();
vm.DropDown = ls;  // where vm.DropDown = List<SelectListItem>();
return View(vm);
```

then on your view you can reference that

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.lob_name, Model.DropDown)
```

with your model add the select list

```
public class LObmodel
{
    public int LOB_ID { get; set; }
    public string LOB_NAME { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> DropDown { get; set; }
}
```

then the top of your view would be

```
@model LObmodel
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your useful insight
Issue 1) passed my list object to view i.e view(obj) i am getting this error[ The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'entitymodel.LobList[]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'entitymodel.LobList'}

Comment: well ty for reply again mate .
Am i missing something here while creating viewmodel obj as above its showing me error i.e the type or namespace VIEWMODEL missing . do i need to add any reference

Comment: you need to create the view model.  it is a class where you define all of the fields and lists that you want to pass to the view.  then initialize the class, populate it and send it to the view.

Comment: yes i am doing so , would you please look into my code . see my main post i posted my fields 2 classes and also controller methods .

Comment: so instead of viewmodel in my code use lobmodel and add the list select list item to that class

Comment: yes done so next do i need to pass the selected list obj to view i.e return view (ls)

Comment: in view i done something like this to capture the view(ls) i.e
@model  IEnumerable<iWiseapp.Models.LObmodel>

If i do so the DROPDOWN binding is not working i.e error with second part

I am really sorry totrouble you over n over

Comment: see the change to my code above.  Making those changes everything should work for you

Comment: Thanks Matt Bodily finally i have done something with your suggestions sadly were the progress is halted for 2 days beco of this issue  :) Ty for help and Ty

Comment: Hey small very minor issue when i am selecting some name in dropdown after clicking submit i am getting id to controller not selected name ?/

Comment: the value will be passed to the controller.  if you want the name passed instead then set the name to the value

Comment: ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = temp.LOB_NAME, Text = temp.LOB_ID.ToString() }); changed like this but in dropdown now id's comming and name coming to controller .. any way around ?

Comment: pass name to both value and text

Comment: yes you insights are very helpful ty friend :) many people are lucky to have people like you

Comment: Hey is there any way i can fallow you and learn something . i am very eager to learn and do something :) Ty i just need your tips to grow up

Comment: I am not sure,  if you click my name it will take you to my profile and you can see the answers that I have given in the past.  May be something there that will help :)

Comment: ok mate i will closely fallow you . and i will hope some how you will find my posts when i post which you can enlighten for my better carrier. Ty so much for your time , Have a nice day

Comment: do this above mentioned scenario helpful to do cascading drop dowm or else i need to know something ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem .
But i changed the view code of DDL using this code :

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ClassID, (SelectList)ViewBag.ClassName);
```

The dropdownlist will bind to your model class called ClassID You will not be able to post the textual value of the ddl to the controller, only the ID behind the ddl.

Comment: Ty for your comment . Data via viewbag is not my aim actually :) via view and strongly type . Well if you are also learner like me very new to mvc . I advice to fallow above approach  Matt Bodily mentioned :) Anyways ty for your reply Ty .