# Get the value of Drop Down List in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get the value of the DropDownList of my view .

I send my collection in each DDL using viewbag like this :

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ClassRepository objclassrep = new ClassRepository();
        DegreeRepositor objdegreerep=new DegreeRepositor();
        FacultyRepositor objfactulyrep=new FacultyRepositor();
        LessonRepository objLessonRep=new LessonRepository();
        MajorRepository objmajorrep=new MajorRepository();
        SemesterRepositor objsemesterrep=new SemesterRepositor();
        TeacherRepositor objteacherrep=new TeacherRepositor();
        ViewBag.ClassName = new SelectList(objclassrep.GetClasslist(), "Id", "ClassName");
        ViewBag.DegreeName = new SelectList(objdegreerep.GetDegreelist(), "Id", "DegreeName");
        ViewBag.FacultyName = new SelectList(objfactulyrep.GetFacultylist(), "Id", "FacultyName");
        ViewBag.LessonName = new SelectList(objLessonRep.GetLessonlist(), "Id", "LessonName");
        ViewBag.MajorName = new SelectList(objmajorrep.GetMajorlist(), "Id", "MajorName");
        ViewBag.TeacherName = new SelectList(objteacherrep.GetTeacherlist(), "Id", "LastName");
        ViewBag.SemesterName = new SelectList(objsemesterrep.GetSemesterlist(), "Id", "SemesterName");





        return View("Create");

        // return View();
    }
```

So the create view code :

```
@model DomainClasses.Schedule

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Schedule</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TeacherId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
             @Html.DropDownList("TeacherName") 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TeacherId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LessonId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
             @Html.DropDownList("LessonName") 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LessonId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClassId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ClassName") 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DegreeId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("DegreeName") 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DegreeId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FacultyId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("FacultyName") 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FacultyId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SemesterId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
                           @Html.DropDownList("SemesterName") 

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SemesterId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MajorId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
               @Html.DropDownList("MajorName") 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MajorId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfExame)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfExame)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfExame)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Capacity)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Capacity)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Capacity)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.locationOfExame)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.locationOfExame)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.locationOfExame)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

So when i click on the save button all ids are null .But i want to get the value of selected items in DDL .

You can see my create action after postback:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Schedule schedule)
        {
            obj.AddNewSchedule(schedule);
            obj.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Schedule");
        }
```

How can i do that ?
Best regards

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594149/dropdownlist-selection-returning-null-mvc4/22594230#22594230

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `@Html.DropDownList("ClassName")` in your controller on postback you must make the controller parameter `(int ClassName)`. You can also do this.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ClassID, (SelectList)ViewBag.ClassName);
```

The dropdownlist will bind to your model class called ClassID
You will not be able to post the textual value of the ddl to the controller, only the ID behind the ddl

Comment: So i changed my code ,but i got several errors in my view.